# How to implement my own javascript code (ad tag code) to get ads from my ad server just like buysellads

Tags: javascript

I have been looking for information about how i can implement my own javascript code (invocation code/ ad tag code) that will get image ads from my ad server to the publishers website, just like buysellads.com or other ad websites.

What I am puzzled about is how they get the ads from the database in the ad server and on to the publishers website.

When I look at some of their codes, I don't see anything about referencing a page which in turn makes calls to the database to get the specified ads.

Please I need help in this regard. Pseudo code or plain explanation would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just create an iFrame to a page on your server, where you'll serve your ads.

Comment: sounds like spam to me, with the domain name in the title

Comment: This is no spam david. I am a real person. The reason i put that there is to be very specific.

Comment: Thanks TJ. But the thing is that I also need it to be asynchronous. I am a newbie and javascript isn't my strongest, but if i get an explanation, I will be able to work with it.

Comment: Ultimately, my goal is to be able to setup an ad network/marketplace.

Comment: Just view source http://s3.buysellads.com/ac/bsa.js

Answer (score 0):

They create a dynamic javascript source that is output by a scripting language like PHP or ASP. That javascript source is included on the page and does document.writes to create the adspace.

Example:

someadscript.js.php:

```
document.write('<a href="<?php echo $ad_url; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $ad_image_url; ?>" /></a>');
```

somepagewithads.html:

```
...

<script type="text/javascript" src="someadsscript.js.php" />

...
```

There are issues with the document.write calls, and it's much more preferable to do something like:

```
...

<div id="some_ad_script_target"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="someadsscript.js.php" />

...
```

And write to the div. That way you don't have to worry about slowing down the page load.

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan. Are you saying that even if the ad network only has someadscript.js it's actually going to call someadscript.js.php to get the info about the ads? This is where I am always getting confused. How they branch into the php page without specifying it in the javascript.